# When should I start sacrificing women at the altar?

Tags: spelunky

In Spelunky, damsels randomly appear and can either be rescued for a health-restoring kiss

[image]

or sacrificed at an altar to gain favour with Kali, who will give items as a reward

[image]

If I'm low on health, it makes sense to save them; and if I have tons, it makes sense to sacrifice them. But when I'm just starting out, with 4 health and few/no items, is it more advantageous to gain health or gather favour for items?

Comment: That title though.

Comment: Ask your local shaman. They generally suggest that you should start with smaller animals first, then move up to small children before - oh... wait... *Spelunky*. Nevermind then.

Comment: You might want to edit the title. Technically, a damsel can be a woman, man, pug or (rarely) sloth! http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Damsel#Types_of_Damsel (I recommend setting it to all pugs, all the time.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Sacrifices are a risk-reward thing.**

When you accumulate enough [favor](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Altar#Favor), Kali will reward you.

The first reward is granted when you reach 8 favor. A Damsel grants 8 when stunned and 4 when dead. You either get:

- Climbing Gloves
- Pitcher's Mitt
- Spring Shoes
- Spike Shoes
- Cape
- Spectacles
- Bomb Paste
- Compass

(Sacrificing a Mystery Box will award you with an [Eggplant](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Eggplant))

Those are nice, but the big thing to get is the [Kapala](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Kapala), at 16 favor. This item is guaranteed.

The Kapala heals you when you collect enough blood. You collect blood by hurting enemies and then touching the blood droplets. Once you have collected enough blood, you gain +1 health and you can repeat this indefinitely. It's a very useful item, if you plan to go [to the City of Gold](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/The_City_of_Gold) (and beyond), because in order to reach the city, you have to meet certain conditions, and of of that is to kill yourself at [a certain place](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/The_Moai) and [having a certain item](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Ankh).

The last reward is at 32 favor - Kali will grant you +8 HP.
I personally wouldn't go for it, but if you have the time and resources (sacrifices), it could pay off. If you plan to go to the Golden City, try to get this *after* you got the [Hedjet](http://spelunky.wikia.com/wiki/Hedjet).

Kalis altar will not spawn on the first level of the mines and most bonus levels, so you can safely rescue the damsel.

What I do (and have seen other runners do) is to **do sacrifices as early and fast as possible** to have a chance at the Kapala, since the early levels are not particularly hard. If you are lucky, you can get 16 favor on the same level, provided there are other valid sacrifices besides the damsel.

Comment: Thanks! Very comprehensive answer. I think I'll take your advice and start sacrificing more often.

Answer (score 0):

**As soon as possible.**

It takes two dasmels (or less if you sacrifice some cavemen) to receive the Kapala, which gives you health points from collecting drops of blood.

The two single health points that you miss out on, are easily recouped by then running around and hitting bats, spiders, snakes etc and collecting their blood.

Answer (score -1):

You should  start whenever you want!! It is best to go to the altar at the start (second level because there are no altars in LVL one) because you have no tools, and the more stuff you sacrafice the better the gifts get!! If you are short on life though (short means 1 or 2 lives) you should get to the end and get more lives. I hope this helped, and also did you know that you can give shopkeepers golden totems for more money than you get at the end? Thanks!!